# Writing to json file using function return data in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

> I need to add the function getvalues returned dictionary into the "data.update".
>   I can add as seperate json. but unable to add it inside the fields key. please, check the output and desired output.

This is the code i have written:

```
import json 
import csv
import glob
import os



csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
name = (os.path.splitext('file.csv')[0])
exampleReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
exampleData = list(exampleReader)



def getvalues():
    for row in exampleData[:1]:
        lis = {}
        for r in row:
            lis.update({r:r})
        return lis


data = {}  

data.update({  

  "pattern": name+'.csv',
  "source_args": {
    "encoding": "UTF-16"
  },
  "parser_args": {
    "type": "csv",
    "delimiter": ","
  },
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": name,
      "fields": {


      }
    }
  ]

})

result =json.dumps(data)
result1 =json.dumps(getvalues())
file = open("data.json","w")
file.write(result)
file.write(result1)
```

Here is the actual output and desired output:

```
#Output : {"pattern": "file.csv", 
            "source_args": 
              {
               "encoding": "UTF-16"
              }, 
             "parser_args": {
                 "type": "csv", 
                 "delimiter": ","
              }, "outputs": 
                   [
                   {
                    "name": "file", 
                    "fields": {}
                    }
            ]}
           {
           "facility_id": "facility_id", 
           "facility_type": "facility_type", 
           "facility_name": "facility_name", 
           "facility_branch": "facility_branch", 
           }
    #Desired Output : {"pattern": "file.csv", 
            "source_args": 
              {
               "encoding": "UTF-16"
              }, 
             "parser_args": {
                 "type": "csv", 
                 "delimiter": ","
              }, "outputs": 
                   [
                   {
                    "name": "file", 
                    "fields": {
                     "facility_id": "facility_id", 
                     "facility_type": "facility_type", 
                     "facility_name": "facility_name", 
                     "facility_branch": "facility_branch", 
                     }
                    }
            ]}
```

> Please, Let me know how can i accomplish this.
>
> Update: ERROR
>   If i add the function directly in the following way. **fields { getvalues() }**. I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chej.py", line 50, in <module>
    getvalues()
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: the problem is with `fields` ?

Comment: Yes, I need add the field values (facility_id , facility type etc in between fields{}) from the data which i fetched using getvalues() function

Comment: Then you can  call the function there and add the list there right ? like this : `"fields": { getvalues() }`

Comment: I am getting the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chej.py", line 50, in <module>
    getvalues()
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Can you trace back the full error in question ? Check also the indentation of return in that function it should outside of the loop.

Comment: I have updated the error in the question. indention of return is not outside the loop.

Comment: Dude A function will only call once. When you returns in each loop it can't get each times function to be called. When the next time function calls it will start at first. So you can append it to a list and finally you can return that list. Other ways it only executes first value

Comment: I have updated the loop results to dictionary and returning that dictionary once the for loop exists. I have tried changing indention of return too. Even then i am getting the same error bro.

Comment: Dude just do like this `fields: getvalues() ` remove `{ }`

Comment: Bro, Thank you I really didn't try by removing brackets. I really wasted lots of time without knowing this. Thank You so much its working.

Comment: Cool bro.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
"outputs": [
{
  "name": name,
  "fields": getvalues()
}
```

]